# Does Firebase A/B experiments support sending 'data' type notification on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-ab-testing

I am setting up an A/B experiment in Firebase dashboard. When I create the experiment I only get an option for sending 'notification' type push messages, which has certain limitations like background, image,etc.

Is there any way, I can set up 'data' messages, for firebase A/B experiment ?

The Firebase console UI only gives the notification option.
My client is Android Device.

Comment: *firebaser here* I don't think this is possible at the moment, but I'll ask around.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible, although if this is something that's important for you, please go ahead and [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), describing your use case.

That said, you can accomplish nearly all data-only message experiments with a [Remote Config experiment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/abtest-config). You might want to look into that as another possibility.